# Stylesheet not applying to sinatra erb views

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra

My stylesheet is applying to some elements of my app and not others, and I'm not sure why.

Here is my document structure:

[image: Document structure]

Currently, the stylesheet is being applied to index.erb and contacts.erb, but not the others in the tree, and I'm not sure why.

In my layout I've specified: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the routes to your pages (that work and don’t)? Your `href` is relative, so if any aren’t single level the page won’t find the stylesheet.

Comment: Do all the files use the layout? What are the URLs of the pages that do, and that don't use the CSS?

Comment: The routes that work are '/' and '/contacts'. Those that don't are '/contacts/new' aka add contact, '/contacts/:id' aka specific contact, and '/contacts/:id/edit' aka edit specific contact. And yes, all the files use the layout, it's saved properly within views.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a relative reference to your stylesheet, so the browser will request it relative to the current url. This means for `/` and `/contacts` the browser will request `/styles.css` and so find it, but for example `/contacts/1` it will request `/contacts/style.css` which doesn’t exist. If you check your logs you’ll likely see a load of 404s where this has happened.

The solution is to use an absolute path for your stylesheet. Assuming you app is mounted at the root of you server (i.e. requests are made to e.g. `http://example.com/contacts/1`) you can do this by just adding a `/` to the beginning of the `href`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

A more robust solution would be to use the [`url` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs), which will ensure the correct url will be used even if your app is mounted at another point (e.g. within a Rails app) or is behind a proxy:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= url("/style.css")%>">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Can you elaborate on why the bottom solution is more robust? I literally just started working with Sinatra today, so any clarification would really be appreciated.

Comment: @Zack Using Rack (the Ruby web server interface that Sinatra and most other frameworks use) you can create an app that contain other apps which are mounted at various points in the master app. For example your app could be mounted at `/foo` within a larger app, so urls would be e.g. `/foo/contacts/1`. The stylesheet would be at `/foo/style.css`. Using `url` would take this int account and generate the correct url without you having to make any changes manually.

Comment: Also, if your app is behind a reverse proxy like Apache or Nginx, so that the app server machine is `my-internal-name.internal` but the “real” address is `myserver.com` then `url` will create the correct (external) url. This is more useful for redirects which should be an absolute url than your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

the public folder is always taken to store the css,js files it will be store in the cache of the browser once you are in the production environment