# Public Directory Not Being Served With Sinatra

Tags: heroku, sinatra, rackup

As the title says, I cannot get Heroku to use my public assets.

Locally, when running my app with `shotgun` it works. But with `rackup` (what Heroku uses), the css and assets 404.

I've tried a bunch of answers on here ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055489/sinatra-static-assets-are-not-found-when-using-rackup?rq=1), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055489/sinatra-static-assets-are-not-found-when-using-rackup/5255635), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153013/stylesheet-not-applying-to-sinatra-erb-views)) but none have worked.

Here's my directory structure:

[image: dir struct]

My config.ru:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

require File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

run BikeShareApp
```

And my controller:

```
class BikeShareApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :'home/index'
  end

  get '/stations' do
    @stations = Station.all
    erb :'stations/index'
  end
end
```

EDIT: This is how I'm referencing my assets by the way

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Following [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby) guide and putting this in my config.ru worked:

```
run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    }
  ]
}
```